# Woocommerce variable products: Sorry, this product is unavailable. Please choose a different combination

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have a problem with woocommerce variable products in specific page. When I set the attributes it says: "Sorry, this product is unavailable. Please choose a different combination.", but the products exist in database. Anyway i tried to delete all the products, and set them again. The page worked correctly but after 5 days the issue returned. Now not only not match with products, it doesnt have all the variation i have set. Only one variation in each attribute. I tried to increase the limit in config.php but nothing happens.  I am using a paid flatsome theme, and the latest versions in wordpress and woocommerce. I search everywhere in the web, but i have not found any solution. This issue happens only in one variable page. The other three work perfectly

Does anyone have the same issue?

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Vaggelis

Comment: Did you enable stock management in product page?

Comment: Hello @Vel and thanks for your answer yes it is anabled and it had values too

Comment: i disabled it, but nothing happend. I have the same results. i reenabled again and still the same

Comment: can you share me the URL?

Comment: https://rafodomi.eu/shop/%cf%86%cf%84%ce%b9%ce%b1%cf%87%cf%84%ce%bf-%ce%bc%ce%bf%ce%bd%ce%bf%cf%83-%cf%83%ce%bf%cf%85/%cf%81%ce%b1%cf%86%ce%b9%ce%b5%cf%81%ce%b1-%ce%bc%ce%b5-4-%ce%b5%cf%80%ce%b9%cf%80%ce%b5%ce%b4%ce%b1-%ce%ba%ce%b1%ce%b8-%cf%85%cf%88%ce%bf%cf%83/

Comment: as you can see the it loads the image of the product but it doesnt load the price.

Comment: I think you didnt enter price for variation/ https://i.stack.imgur.com/bwNBJ.png

Comment: i have enter the price in variations but suddenly now it is shows the products fine. i am very confused. let me work on it please. any way thanks you very much for your help. can i pm you if i stack again?

Comment: Seems due to language issue. not sure. Yes. you can.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After hours of searching i found the solution in my problem. The problem was in ajax_variation_threshold. I had to increase the limit of the requests. So i had to add in my functions.php this code:

```
function woo_custom_ajax_variation_threshold( $qty, $product ) {
return 50;
}       
add_filter( 'woocommerce_ajax_variation_threshold', 'woo_custom_ajax_variation_threshold', 10, 2 );
```

this seems to work properly.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and resolved it by removing a variation which was not added by myself, and it showed as "any item" in the variation which has no price set. 
Remove that variation with no price set!!!

Comment: Can you please add more details to your answer. An example, a screenshot, or a piece of code to do what you are suggesting in your answer. This will make it easier for the next person who comes looking for a solution to this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Set an attribute first if you need a variation. The variation which has no price set has to remove form the list.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and resolved it by removing a product variation which was not added,like  it showed as "any item" in the variation which has no price set. Remove that variation with no price, it will set

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).